# Get RMSE of GARCH in R using rugarch

Tags: r

I have written a piece of code in R to calculate and display standard plots for a time series which looks like this. The contents of the `DWDMData.csv` is as follows

```
Time,IndexValue,Volatility
1,101.22,0.00526633297276868
2,102.18,0.00409956537347567
3,102.44,0.00110367145014756
```

The code for this is

```
library(rugarch)
dataset <- read.csv("DWDMData.csv",TRUE)
memdata = dataset[,c("Volatility")] 
memtrain = head(memdata, 450) 
memtest = dataset[451:500,c("Volatility")]

diff.memtrain = diff(memtrain)


arch.spec.std = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(0,1)),mean.model= list(armaOrder=c(0,2)),distribution.model = "std")
arch.fit.std = ugarchfit(spec=arch.spec.std, data=diff.memtrain,solver.control=list(trace = 1))
plot(arch.fit.std)
```

However, I wanted the next 50 prediction to compare RMSE error and alsothe residuals from the dataset used to train. How do I do it?

Comment: #1 Please provide a reproducible example with dummy data instead of `DWDMData.csv`. #2 `residuals(arch.fit.std)`?

Comment: @lukeA the DWDMData.csv just has that data. I also don't know much of R. Soo little that i barely know hot to init an array